# Why is there both a resolver and a handler in dnslib's DNSServer()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dns

I am trying to understand the resolving process in [`dnslib`](https://bitbucket.org/paulc/dnslib). Specifically, I am using the [`proxy.py`](https://bitbucket.org/paulc/dnslib/src/default/dnslib/proxy.py) example to implement a local DNS proxy which will send a request to specific servers based on the query.

(copy of `proxy.py`):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function

import binascii,socket,struct

from dnslib import DNSRecord,RCODE
from dnslib.server import DNSServer,DNSHandler,BaseResolver,DNSLogger

class ProxyResolver(BaseResolver):
    """
        Proxy resolver - passes all requests to upstream DNS server and
        returns response

        Note that the request/response will be each be decoded/re-encoded
        twice:

        a) Request packet received by DNSHandler and parsed into DNSRecord
        b) DNSRecord passed to ProxyResolver, serialised back into packet
           and sent to upstream DNS server
        c) Upstream DNS server returns response packet which is parsed into
           DNSRecord
        d) ProxyResolver returns DNSRecord to DNSHandler which re-serialises
           this into packet and returns to client

        In practice this is actually fairly useful for testing but for a
        'real' transparent proxy option the DNSHandler logic needs to be
        modified (see PassthroughDNSHandler)

    """

    def __init__(self,address,port,timeout=0):
        self.address = address
        self.port = port
        self.timeout = timeout

    def resolve(self,request,handler):
        try:
            if handler.protocol == 'udp':
                proxy_r = request.send(self.address,self.port,
                                timeout=self.timeout)
            else:
                proxy_r = request.send(self.address,self.port,
                                tcp=True,timeout=self.timeout)
            reply = DNSRecord.parse(proxy_r)
        except socket.timeout:
            reply = request.reply()
            reply.header.rcode = getattr(RCODE,'NXDOMAIN')

        return reply

class PassthroughDNSHandler(DNSHandler):
    """
        Modify DNSHandler logic (get_reply method) to send directly to
        upstream DNS server rather then decoding/encoding packet and
        passing to Resolver (The request/response packets are still
        parsed and logged but this is not inline)
    """
    def get_reply(self,data):
        host,port = self.server.resolver.address,self.server.resolver.port

        request = DNSRecord.parse(data)
        self.server.logger.log_request(self,request)

        if self.protocol == 'tcp':
            data = struct.pack("!H",len(data)) + data
            response = send_tcp(data,host,port)
            response = response[2:]
        else:
            response = send_udp(data,host,port)

        reply = DNSRecord.parse(response)
        self.server.logger.log_reply(self,reply)

        return response

def send_tcp(data,host,port):
    """
        Helper function to send/receive DNS TCP request
        (in/out packets will have prepended TCP length header)
    """
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((host,port))
    sock.sendall(data)
    response = sock.recv(8192)
    length = struct.unpack("!H",bytes(response[:2]))[0]
    while len(response) - 2 < length:
        response += sock.recv(8192)
    sock.close()
    return response

def send_udp(data,host,port):
    """
        Helper function to send/receive DNS UDP request
    """
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.sendto(data,(host,port))
    response,server = sock.recvfrom(8192)
    sock.close()
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import argparse,sys,time

    p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="DNS Proxy")
    p.add_argument("--port","-p",type=int,default=53,
                    metavar="<port>",
                    help="Local proxy port (default:53)")
    p.add_argument("--address","-a",default="",
                    metavar="<address>",
                    help="Local proxy listen address (default:all)")
    p.add_argument("--upstream","-u",default="8.8.8.8:53",
            metavar="<dns server:port>",
                    help="Upstream DNS server:port (default:8.8.8.8:53)")
    p.add_argument("--tcp",action='store_true',default=False,
                    help="TCP proxy (default: UDP only)")
    p.add_argument("--timeout","-o",type=float,default=5,
                    metavar="<timeout>",
                    help="Upstream timeout (default: 5s)")
    p.add_argument("--passthrough",action='store_true',default=False,
                    help="Dont decode/re-encode request/response (default: off)")
    p.add_argument("--log",default="request,reply,truncated,error",
                    help="Log hooks to enable (default: +request,+reply,+truncated,+error,-recv,-send,-data)")
    p.add_argument("--log-prefix",action='store_true',default=False,
                    help="Log prefix (timestamp/handler/resolver) (default: False)")
    args = p.parse_args()

    args.dns,_,args.dns_port = args.upstream.partition(':')
    args.dns_port = int(args.dns_port or 53)

    print("Starting Proxy Resolver (%s:%d -> %s:%d) [%s]" % (
                        args.address or "*",args.port,
                        args.dns,args.dns_port,
                        "UDP/TCP" if args.tcp else "UDP"))

    resolver = ProxyResolver(args.dns,args.dns_port,args.timeout)
    handler = PassthroughDNSHandler if args.passthrough else DNSHandler
    logger = DNSLogger(args.log,args.log_prefix)
    udp_server = DNSServer(resolver,
                           port=args.port,
                           address=args.address,
                           logger=logger,
                           handler=handler)
    udp_server.start_thread()

    if args.tcp:
        tcp_server = DNSServer(resolver,
                               port=args.port,
                               address=args.address,
                               tcp=True,
                               logger=logger,
                               handler=handler)
        tcp_server.start_thread()

    while udp_server.isAlive():
        time.sleep(1)
```

I have successfully injected the business logic of my interactions in the `get_reply` method of `PassthroughDNSHandler`:

```
def get_reply(self, data):
    host, port = self.server.resolver.address, self.server.resolver.port

    request = DNSRecord.parse(data)
    query = str(request.questions[0].qname)
    if query.endswith('.example.info.'):
        server = "192.168.10.1"
    elif any(query.endswith(x) for x in ["example.net.", "example.com."]):
        server = "10.24.131.10"
    else:
        server = "1.1.1.1"

    log.debug(f"{query} redirected to {server}")
    response = send_udp(data, server, port)
    reply = DNSRecord.parse(response)
```

This works as expected, the right DNS servers are queried depending on the request.

**The part which I do not understand is the involvement of `ProxyResolver` in the initialization of the server.**

```
resolver = ProxyResolver(args.dns, args.dns_port, args.timeout)
    udp_server = DNSServer(resolver, port=53, address="127.0.0.1", handler=PassthroughDNSHandler)
```

What is `resolver` needed for?

As far as I understand, the packet received on `127.0.0.1:53` is passed, via `handler`, to `PassthroughDNSHandler` and actually processed in `get_reply()`.

It is then further sent to the relevant upstream server via `send_udp()` and the response is forwarded back to the requesting client.

**At what point does `resolver` gets into the picture and what is its role?**

I put a breakpoint in the `resolve()` method of `ProxyResolver` and it is never hit.

Comment: A proxy, for any kind of protocol in fact, is both a client and a server: it needs to act as if it is a server for the client connecting to it, but will certainly need to act as a client when going "forward" and connect to the real server. Hence here you have a DNS server (`DNSServer`) but it will need itself to resolve data through the DNS, hence it needs a `resolver` for it, the client part.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: yes, but the question is why both `PassthroughDNSHandler` and `resolve`